# Prettier splits 1 60-character line of JS into 11 lines with printWidth at 2500 and singleAttributePerLine disabled?

Tags: vscode-extensions, prettier, formatter

Before Prettier:

[image]

```
console.log(countSubTrees(4, [[0, 1],[1, 2],[0, 3]], "bbbb"));
```

After Prettier:

[image]

```
console.log(
    countSubTrees(
        4,
        [
            [0, 1],
            [1, 2],
            [0, 3],
        ],
        "bbbb"
    )
);
```

Does anyone understand why it does this? Is it because it contains a 2-dimensional array? I thought this extension was pretty ubiquitous, but I have a hard time imagining this is what anyone would want their code to look like. Usually it's okayish but situations like these make it really hard to want to leave the extension enabled.

The only things my Googling has returned to change this is to increase printWidth and, for certain languages, disable singleAttributePerLine, but neither fixes what you see here. Am I missing something here? This is just bizarre to me.

Comment: Have you contacted the authors of the program and checked they bugtracking system? Asking about someone else's intentions in a programming forum is kind-of moot. Also, as with most formatting issues, this is mostly about opinions.

Comment: I was kind of hoping to gather opinions; the general opinion on this extension seems to be favorable, so I was just trying to understand what a veteran user would do in this situation; whether there is a workaround that I'm missing or if popular opinion would dictate that the second code snippet actually looks better than the first. I care mostly about others' readability of my code, so if this is the case, then I guess it's fine. But my thinking was that stretching a short line of code out into 11 lines introduces a lot of unnecessary scrolling and makes it feel overly verbose.